# Flutter: Only gridview is scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, widget

I am trying to make my whole page scrollable on my app, but for some unknown reason, only the grid view is scrolling can someone help me figure out why this is happening?
Thanks a million.

Here is my code:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: SizeConfig.screenHeight / 2.5,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/food2.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      ),
      const Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          "Donation Cards",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
            fontSize: 31,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Divider(color: Colors.black38),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        children: _listItem
            .map((item) => Card(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 0,
                  //child: GestureDetector(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, item.route),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(item.image),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      )),
                ))
            .toList(),
      ))
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Thanks once again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to use a scrollable widget as a parent of everything which should be scrolled. Currently GridView is the only scrollable widget in your code.

Comment: I tried adding the first container with a SingleChildScrollView but it's gives me an empty screen. Can u please refactor my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colunm wrap with singlechildscrollview and give gridview physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: it throws a. constraints error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).